# How to install inf file from base directory from Batch File (.bat)?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, inf

I want to make a Batch File (`.bat`) to install an `.inf` file that is located in the base directory of the `.bat` file. I managed to install the `.inf`, but only if I specify the full directory. How can I install the `.inf` file without specifying the full directory?

Here's what I have so far:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe "DroidInstaller.inf"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So your `inf` file and your batch file are both in `system32`?

Comment: Why would you not want to specify the full path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite vague. If both files (your `installer.bat` and the `inf` file) are in the same directory then you can add `pushd "%~dp0"` at the start of your batch-script:

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
%SystemRoot%\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe "DroidInstaller.inf"
```

This will set the working directory to the directory where your batch-script runs in. If this directory is the same as the directory of your `inf` file then you are able to call the `DroidInstaller.inf` the way you did in your question.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted.